# HicariDataSource with other datasource

Tags: java, spring, database, datasource, connection-pooling

I have a custom java datasource class which has database connection ability as well as connection pooling option. However, I am not very satisfied with connection pooling functions there. Therefore, I decided to use HicariDataSource class with HicariConfig class as wrapper classes to implement database connection pooling. However, I am still using the custom datasource class for database connection because the custom datasource class has some good connection functions which I do not want to write again. After running the application this way with the HicariDataSource and the customer datasource class inside it,  It resolved some Database Pool exception happening before, and it is performing well without any problem. However, Chatgpt is suggesting that HicariDataSource is designed to connect to the database by itself. If I use another datasource class for connection, I will not get proper advantage from HicariDataSource. On the other hand, I see in the docs that the setDataSource method of HicariConfig is designed to work with other datasource classes for connection. Now I want expert opinion in this filed to tell me if I really lose advantage of HicariDataSource while using it with a different datasource class for connection?